# Urdf spawner - process has died

Tags: urdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

while going through this tutorials [Using A URDF in Gazebo](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.9/Using_A_URDF_In_Gazebo) i encountered a problem while trying to execute following code:  `roslaunch rrbot_gazebo rrbot_world.launch`

The process stoppes with following error:

```
[urdf_spawner-4] process has died [pid 5480, exit code 1, cmd /home/schultza/catkin_ws/src/gazebo_ros_pkgs/gazebo_ros/scripts/spawn_model -urdf -model rrbot -param robot_description __name:=urdf_spawner __log:=/home/schultza/.ros/log/9a635d4c-1bde-11e4-92a6-485ab604aada/urdf_spawner-4.log].
log file: /home/schultza/.ros/log/9a635d4c-1bde-11e4-92a6-485ab604aada/urdf_spawner-4*.log
```

I am using ROS - Indigo with Ubuntu 14.04 and Gazebo 2.2

Has someone an idea where my problem is?

Thanks in advance!

---

Edit#1
I cant find the exact urdf-spawner-4*.log file in the directory so I just post the logs which I found:

Log1: master.log

```
[rosmaster.main][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:52:42,702: initialization complete, waiting for shutdown
[rosmaster.main][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:52:42,702: Starting ROS Master Node
[xmlrpc][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:52:42,703: XML-RPC server binding to 0.0.0.0:11311
[xmlrpc][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:52:42,704: Started XML-RPC server [http://Andreas:11311/]
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:52:42,704: Master initialized: port[11311], uri[http://Andreas:11311/]
[xmlrpc][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:52:42,704: xml rpc node: starting XML-RPC server
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:52:42,781: +PARAM [/run_id] by /roslaunch
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:52:42,784: +PARAM [/roslaunch/uris/host_andreas__47756] by /roslaunch
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:52:42,878: +PARAM [/rosversion] by /roslaunch
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:52:42,878: +PARAM [/use_sim_time] by /roslaunch
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:52:42,878: +PARAM [/rosdistro] by /roslaunch
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:52:42,878: +PARAM [/robot_description] by /roslaunch
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:52:43,729: +SERVICE [/rosout/get_loggers] /rosout http://Andreas:59776/
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:52:43,730: +SERVICE [/rosout/set_logger_level] /rosout http://Andreas:59776/
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:52:43,739: +SUB [/clock] /rosout http://Andreas:59776/
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:52:43,740: +PUB [/rosout_agg] /rosout http://Andreas:59776/
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:52:43,743: +SUB [/rosout] /rosout http://Andreas:59776/
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:52:46,771: +PUB [/rosout] /gazebo http://Andreas:56281/
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:52:46,782: +SERVICE [/gazebo/get_loggers] /gazebo http://Andreas:56281/
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:52:46,784: +SERVICE [/gazebo/set_logger_level] /gazebo http://Andreas:56281/
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:52:46,792: +SUB [/clock] /gazebo http://Andreas:56281/
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:52:46,809: publisherUpdate[/rosout] -> http://Andreas:59776/
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:52:47,646: +PUB [/clock] /gazebo http://Andreas:56281/
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:52:47,648: +SERVICE [/gazebo/spawn_gazebo_model] /gazebo http://Andreas:56281/
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:52:47,649: +SERVICE [/gazebo/spawn_sdf_model] /gazebo http://Andreas:56281/
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:52:47,651: +SERVICE [/gazebo/spawn_urdf_model] /gazebo http://Andreas:56281/
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:52:47,652: +SERVICE [/gazebo/delete_model] /gazebo http://Andreas:56281/
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:52:47,654: +SERVICE [/gazebo/get_model_properties] /gazebo http://Andreas:56281/
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:52:47,655: +SERVICE [/gazebo/get_model_state] /gazebo http://Andreas:56281/
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:52:47,656: +SERVICE [/gazebo/get_world_properties] /gazebo http://Andreas:56281/
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:52:47,658: +SERVICE [/gazebo/get_joint_properties] /gazebo http://Andreas:56281/
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:52:47,659: +SERVICE [/gazebo/get_link_properties] /gazebo http://Andreas:56281/
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:52:47,661: +SERVICE [/gazebo/get_link_state] /gazebo http://Andreas:56281/
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:52:47,662: +SERVICE [/gazebo/get_physics_properties] /gazebo http://Andreas:56281/
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:52:47,663: +PUB [/gazebo/link_states] /gazebo http://Andreas:56281/
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:52:47,664: +PUB [/gazebo/model_states] /gazebo http://Andreas:56281/
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:52:47,665: +SERVICE [/gazebo/set_link_properties] /gazebo http://Andreas:56281/
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:52:47,666: +SERVICE [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] /gazebo http://Andreas:56281/
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:52:47,668: +SERVICE [/gazebo/set_model_state] /gazebo http://Andreas:56281/
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:52:47,669: +SERVICE [/gazebo/set_model_configuration] /gazebo http://Andreas:56281/
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:52:47,671: +SERVICE [/gazebo/set_joint_properties] /gazebo http://Andreas:56281/
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:52:47,673: +SERVICE [/gazebo/set_link_state] /gazebo http://Andreas:56281/
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:52:47,679: +SUB [/gazebo/set_link_state] /gazebo http://Andreas:56281/
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:52:47,685: +SUB [/gazebo/set_model_state] /gazebo http://Andreas:56281/
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:52:47,686: +SERVICE [/gazebo/pause_physics] /gazebo http://Andreas:56281/
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:52:47,687: +SERVICE [/gazebo/unpause_physics] /gazebo http://Andreas:56281/
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:52:47,688: +SERVICE [/gazebo/apply_body_wrench] /gazebo http://Andreas:56281/
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:52:47,689: +SERVICE [/gazebo/apply_joint_effort] /gazebo http://Andreas:56281/
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:52:47,690: +SERVICE [/gazebo/clear_joint_forces] /gazebo http://Andreas:56281/
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:52:47,691: +SERVICE [/gazebo/clear_body_wrenches] /gazebo http://Andreas:56281/
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:52:47,692: +SERVICE [/gazebo/reset_simulation] /gazebo http://Andreas:56281/
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:52:47,693: +SERVICE [/gazebo/reset_world] /gazebo http://Andreas:56281/
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:52:47,694: +PARAM [/use_sim_time] by /gazebo
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:52:47,711: publisherUpdate[/clock] -> http://Andreas:59776/
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:52:47,711: publisherUpdate[/clock] -> http://Andreas:56281/
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:52:47,742: +SERVICE [/gazebo/set_parameters] /gazebo http://Andreas:56281/
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:52:47,746: +PUB [/gazebo/parameter_descriptions] /gazebo http://Andreas:56281/
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:52:47,751: +PUB [/gazebo/parameter_updates] /gazebo http://Andreas:56281/
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:52:47,760: +PARAM [/gazebo/time_step] by /gazebo
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:52:47,761: +PARAM [/gazebo/max_update_rate] by /gazebo
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:52:47,762: +PARAM [/gazebo/gravity_x] by /gazebo
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:52:47,763: +PARAM [/gazebo/gravity_y] by /gazebo
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:52:47,764: +PARAM [/gazebo/gravity_z] by /gazebo
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:52:47,764: +PARAM [/gazebo/auto_disable_bodies] by /gazebo
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:52:47,765: +PARAM [/gazebo/sor_pgs_precon_iters] by /gazebo
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:52:47,766: +PARAM [/gazebo/sor_pgs_iters] by /gazebo
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:52:47,767: +PARAM [/gazebo/sor_pgs_w] by /gazebo
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:52:47,768: +PARAM [/gazebo/sor_pgs_rms_error_tol] by /gazebo
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:52:47,769: +PARAM [/gazebo/cfm] by /gazebo
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:52:47,770: +PARAM [/gazebo/erp] by /gazebo
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:52:47,770: +PARAM [/gazebo/contact_surface_layer] by /gazebo
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:52:47,771: +PARAM [/gazebo/contact_max_correcting_vel] by /gazebo
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:52:47,772: +PARAM [/gazebo/max_contacts] by /gazebo
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:52:47,774: +PARAM [/gazebo/time_step] by /gazebo
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:52:47,775: +PARAM [/gazebo/max_update_rate] by /gazebo
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:52:47,776: +PARAM [/gazebo/gravity_x] by /gazebo
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:52:47,777: +PARAM [/gazebo/gravity_y] by /gazebo
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:52:47,778: +PARAM [/gazebo/gravity_z] by /gazebo
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:52:47,779: +PARAM [/gazebo/auto_disable_bodies] by /gazebo
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:52:47,779: +PARAM [/gazebo/sor_pgs_precon_iters] by /gazebo
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:52:47,780: +PARAM [/gazebo/sor_pgs_iters] by /gazebo
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:52:47,781: +PARAM [/gazebo/sor_pgs_w] by /gazebo
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:52:47,782: +PARAM [/gazebo/sor_pgs_rms_error_tol] by /gazebo
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:52:47,783: +PARAM [/gazebo/cfm] by /gazebo
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:52:47,784: +PARAM [/gazebo/erp] by /gazebo
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:52:47,785: +PARAM [/gazebo/contact_surface_layer] by /gazebo
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:52:47,786: +PARAM [/gazebo/contact_max_correcting_vel] by /gazebo
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:52:47,786: +PARAM [/gazebo/max_contacts] by /gazebo
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:55:16,910: -SUB [/gazebo/set_link_state] /gazebo http://Andreas:56281/
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:55:16,912: -SUB [/gazebo/set_model_state] /gazebo http://Andreas:56281/
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:55:16,914: -PUB [/clock] /gazebo http://Andreas:56281/
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:55:16,916: -PUB [/gazebo/link_states] /gazebo http://Andreas:56281/
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:55:16,918: -PUB [/gazebo/model_states] /gazebo http://Andreas:56281/
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:55:16,919: -SERVICE [/gazebo/spawn_gazebo_model] /gazebo rosrpc://Andreas:50458
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:55:16,920: publisherUpdate[/clock] -> http://Andreas:59776/
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:55:16,921: publisherUpdate[/clock] -> http://Andreas:56281/
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:55:16,922: -SERVICE [/gazebo/spawn_sdf_model] /gazebo rosrpc://Andreas:50458
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:55:16,925: -SERVICE [/gazebo/spawn_urdf_model] /gazebo rosrpc://Andreas:50458
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:55:16,926: -SERVICE [/gazebo/delete_model] /gazebo rosrpc://Andreas:50458
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:55:16,927: -SERVICE [/gazebo/get_model_properties] /gazebo rosrpc://Andreas:50458
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:55:16,929: -SERVICE [/gazebo/get_model_state] /gazebo rosrpc://Andreas:50458
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:55:16,929: -SERVICE [/gazebo/get_world_properties] /gazebo rosrpc://Andreas:50458
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:55:16,930: -SERVICE [/gazebo/get_joint_properties] /gazebo rosrpc://Andreas:50458
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:55:16,931: -SERVICE [/gazebo/get_link_properties] /gazebo rosrpc://Andreas:50458
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:55:16,932: -SERVICE [/gazebo/get_link_state] /gazebo rosrpc://Andreas:50458
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:55:16,933: -SERVICE [/gazebo/get_physics_properties] /gazebo rosrpc://Andreas:50458
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:55:16,934: -SERVICE [/gazebo/set_link_properties] /gazebo rosrpc://Andreas:50458
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:55:16,935: -SERVICE [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] /gazebo rosrpc://Andreas:50458
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:55:16,936: -SERVICE [/gazebo/set_model_state] /gazebo rosrpc://Andreas:50458
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:55:16,937: -SERVICE [/gazebo/set_model_configuration] /gazebo rosrpc://Andreas:50458
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:55:16,938: -SERVICE [/gazebo/set_joint_properties] /gazebo rosrpc://Andreas:50458
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:55:16,938: -SERVICE [/gazebo/set_link_state] /gazebo rosrpc://Andreas:50458
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:55:16,939: -SERVICE [/gazebo/pause_physics] /gazebo rosrpc://Andreas:50458
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:55:16,940: -SERVICE [/gazebo/unpause_physics] /gazebo rosrpc://Andreas:50458
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:55:16,941: -SERVICE [/gazebo/apply_body_wrench] /gazebo rosrpc://Andreas:50458
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:55:16,942: -SERVICE [/gazebo/apply_joint_effort] /gazebo rosrpc://Andreas:50458
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:55:16,942: -SERVICE [/gazebo/clear_joint_forces] /gazebo rosrpc://Andreas:50458
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:55:16,943: -SERVICE [/gazebo/clear_body_wrenches] /gazebo rosrpc://Andreas:50458
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:55:16,944: -SERVICE [/gazebo/reset_simulation] /gazebo rosrpc://Andreas:50458
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:55:16,945: -SERVICE [/gazebo/reset_world] /gazebo rosrpc://Andreas:50458
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:55:16,947: -PUB [/gazebo/parameter_descriptions] /gazebo http://Andreas:56281/
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:55:16,948: -PUB [/gazebo/parameter_updates] /gazebo http://Andreas:56281/
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:55:16,949: -SERVICE [/gazebo/set_parameters] /gazebo rosrpc://Andreas:50458
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:55:17,124: -PUB [/rosout] /gazebo http://Andreas:56281/
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:55:17,124: publisherUpdate[/rosout] -> http://Andreas:59776/
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:55:17,127: -SUB [/clock] /gazebo http://Andreas:56281/
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:55:17,129: -SERVICE [/gazebo/get_loggers] /gazebo rosrpc://Andreas:50458
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:55:17,130: -SERVICE [/gazebo/set_logger_level] /gazebo rosrpc://Andreas:50458
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:55:17,527: -PUB [/rosout_agg] /rosout http://Andreas:59776/
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:55:17,528: -SUB [/clock] /rosout http://Andreas:59776/
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:55:17,528: -SUB [/rosout] /rosout http://Andreas:59776/
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:55:17,529: -SERVICE [/rosout/get_loggers] /rosout rosrpc://Andreas:50151
[rosmaster.master][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:55:17,529: -SERVICE [/rosout/set_logger_level] /rosout rosrpc://Andreas:50151
[rosmaster.main][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:55:17,549: keyboard interrupt, will exit
[rosmaster.main][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:55:17,549: stopping master...
[rospy.core][INFO] 2014-08-04 15:55:17,549: signal_shutdown [atexit]
```

Log 2: roslaunch.log

> This code block was moved to the following github gist:
> https://gist.github.com/answers-se-migration-openrobotics/921ab9600fa4aa0e030cb372eb80f853

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/188831/urdf-spawner---process-has-died/) by [schultza](https://answers.ros.org/users/18901/schultza/) on ROS Answers with karma: 212 on 2014-08-04

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try installing gazebo as the tutorial  in this answer recommends:

[Answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/193367/still-problems-with-gazebo_ros-and-urdf-spawn/)

---

Originally posted by [schultza](https://answers.ros.org/users/18901/schultza/) with karma: 232 on 2014-09-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1